# How can I correctly set the time of a dateTime field from a front-end form?

Tags: templating, datetime

I am using [jQuery-timepicker](https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker) to give the user an option to pick a starting time and ending time.

My init looks like this:

```
$('.timepicker').timepicker({
    scrollDefault: 'now'
});
```

When I save the entry as attached (screen below) it is displaying the time + 6 minutes.
[image][image]

My template looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="fields[myTimes][{{ block.id }}][fields][startDateTime][date]" class="form-control datepicker" value="{{ block.startDateTime|date('m/d/Y') }}">

<input type="text" name="fields[myTimes][{{ block.id }}][fields][startDateTime][time]" class="form-control timepicker" value="{{ block.startDateTime|date('h:m') }}">

<input type="text" name="fields[myTimes][{{ block.id }}][fields][endDateTime][time]" class="form-control timepicker" value="{{ block.endDateTime|date('h:m') }}">
```

When I save my form, everything looks like it is saving correctly, its always +6 min. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Thank you for any suggestions!

**EDIT**

Here is another example. I have saved for 9:00PM - 10:00PM
It saves correctly, but the template shows +6 still. :)[image][image][image]

Comment: How fascinating. Is your system clock off by 6 minutes? (Wild guess.) Wondering if this happens in more than one environment...

Comment: Strange huh? It doesn't appear that it's the clock. It's almost like it's at the template level - which is why I thought for sure it's something i'm doing (or not doing).

Comment: Yeah... that's super weird. No idea why that would happen, but definitely something xDebug would help figure out.

Comment: Not to be a broken record, but are you definitely seeing this in more than one environment? I assume you would've mentioned if you were seeing six-minute page load times.

Comment: Start time seems to get converted to AM, so there might be some formatting involved.

Comment: We're also in June, which is the sixth month, so m vs M in the formatting? Or the other way around? One is the month number and the other is minutes, can't remember which is which

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your suggestions - I need to keep reading/digging more to fully understand, but it seems that it was just a formatting issue.

```
{{ block.startDateTime|date('H:i:s') }}
```

Renders the correct time on the template.